# Absolute basics - JSON and jQuery $ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to use JSON for the very first time and use GET to pull in data from an external website.

All I want at this point is to pull the data from `ip.jsontest.com` into my JavaScript and then alert my IP address.

I tried following the layout from `api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/`

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
//how do I know what my dataType is?
  url: url,
//Ok, I get this one http://ip.jsontest.com/
  data: data,
/*Don't know what to put in here either, the URL should return "{"ip": "8.8.8.8"}" 
but I don't know what that means for this line.
*/
  success: success
/*I get that this is what to do with the success, but all
I want to do is have the single item object available 
to use in my .js so I am not sure if I am supposed to put 
in a function here and assign it to a var or what.
*/    
});
```

since I don't understand what each of those lines mean... 
I have been trying things like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://ip.jsontest.com/",
    data: {key:key},
    success: function (data) {
    var ip1 = data.ip;
    }
});
```

but putting that in my .js breaks the whole thing... so I was hoping someone could show me the proper way to do it with that info, and then alert the IP address returned...

Comment: 1) Because you know what you're sending. 2) Whatever you're supposed to send, if anything. 3) `success` attribute is a function. But if you declare a variable local to that function it goes out of scope before you can do anything with it. You might want to take a step back and learn some JavaScript basics, especially regarding variable scope.

Comment: You spelled success wrong

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks the whole thing"

Comment: If you don't know what the options mean, then [**why don't you read the documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)??

Comment: Dave, thanks, that info was helpful.

Comment: xd6, corrected, that wasn't the problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data type - the type of data you want to get back from the server. Since you said youre trying to use json I would presume its json.
data - is the data youre posting to the server - since youre not posting any you dont need this.
success - what you want to happen if your ajax call was successful.

try this:

```
success: function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
```